# How to determine if user is coming from thin client or fat client?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sharepoint-2013, vmware, vdi

I need to dynamically display content on a web page based on thin/fat client accessing the page.

I want to be able to programmatically determine if a user is coming from a thin client in my case VMWare VDI vs a thick client desktop, vpn, etc. I would prefer the solution in a client side scripting language such as Javascript if possible.

Comment: if the user opens the page, it is always from a web browser, which is a thin client , or not?

Comment: A user can launch a browser from either a thin client or a fat client, I need to be able to determine which type of client the user launched the browser from.

Comment: have you checked the browser's user agent string?

Comment: Could the client who launches the page supply a url parameter to distinguish the request?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to either the thin or fat client:

- change the user agent to reflect the thin/fat client
- add extra headers into the browser request https://superuser.com/questions/584918/send-a-custom-http-header-to-one-certain-host-only

In any case, you can:

- console.log(navigator) to get client data
- try to detect hardware with something like webgl, example here: http://webglreport.com/,
- or a old example using MAC address here:
  http://carnal0wnage.attackresearch.com/2009/04/detecting-vmware-with-javascript-or-how.html